# confused as to the behavior of this ruby fragment

Tags: ruby

Sorry to ask this but I really need to get this done. I'd like to be able to pass in a string and strip out the stop_words. I have the following:

```
class Query
  def self.normalize term
    stop_words=["a","big","array"]
    term.downcase!
    legit=[]
    if !stop_words.include?(term)
      legit << term
    end
    return legit
  end

  def self.check_parts term
    term_parts=term.split(' ')
    tmp_part=[]
    term_parts.each do |part|
      t=self.normalize part
      tmp_part << t
    end  
    return tmp_part  
  end
end
```

I would think that this would return only terms that are not in the stop_words list but I'm getting back either an empty array or an array of the terms passed in. Like this:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :146 > Query.check_parts "here Is my Char"
 => [[], [], [], ["char"]] 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :147 >
```

What am I doing wrong?

thx in advance

Comment: I have just copied your code and ran it (ruby 1.9.3), and it returns `[["here"], ["is"], ["my"], ["char"]]`, as expected.

Comment: I get expected result on the `ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]`, `ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [i686-linux]`, `ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]`

Comment: side note: this seems like a novice code, it's hardly idiomatic and both methods can be simplified a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to filter out the terms and get an array of downcased words, it is simple.

```
module Query
  StopWords = %w[a big array]
  def self.check_parts string; string.downcase.split(/\s+/) - StopWords end
end

Query.check_parts("here Is my Char") # => ["here", "is", "my", "char"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want the result as an array I don't know but

```
term_parts=term.split(' ')
term_parts.reject { |part| stop_words.include?(part) }
```

You could write what you expect.
By the way, you have an array for array because

```
def self.check_parts term
    term_parts=term.split(' ')
    tmp_part=[]                 # creates an array
    term_parts.each do |part|
      t=self.normalize part     # normalize returns an empty array
                                # or one of only one element (a term).
      tmp_part << t             # you add an array into the array
    end  
    return tmp_part  
  end
```